# VBA - Picture Excel to Outlook with image resizeing

Tags: excel, vba, image, outlook, size

I put together a code which works pretty well, however the picture that is pasted on the email is a bit too small, I would like to make it bigger but I am struggling to find the right code.

Another issue is that the signature is right next to the picture while I would like it to be a few rows below.

Can anyone bring these two features to my code?

```
Sub Print_and_send()
Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sht.Range("D3:Y42")
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Dim OutApp As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim vInspector As Object
Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector

Dim wEditor As Object
Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor


With OutMail
    .To = "youremail"
    .CC = "youremail"

    .Subject = "Test"
    .display


     wEditor.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste



End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that there is an answer to one of the two questions you see why you should have two separate posts. As well it is easier for searchers to find relevant answers to their specific question. You could edit your post to remove the signature question and try a separate on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this code:

```
 For Each shp In wordDoc.InlineShapes
        shp.ScaleHeight = 90
        shp.ScaleWidth = 90
    Next
```

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[Resize a pasted JPEG in a MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446208/resize-a-pasted-jpeg-in-a-mailitem)